# Pass GET parameters with Ruby Curb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use Curb (curb.rubyforge.org) to call a RESTful API that needs parameters supplied in a get request.

I want to fetch a URL like `http://foo.com/bar.xml?bla=blablabla`. I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Curl::Easy.perform("http://foo.com/bar.xml", :bla => 'blablabla') {|curl|
    curl.set_some_headers_if_necessary
}
```

but so far, the only way I can see to do this is by manually including the `?bla=blablabla` in the URL and doing the encoding myself. Surely there is a right way to do this, but I can't figure it out reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using ActiveSupport '~> 3.0', there's an easy workaround - `to_query` method, which converts hash to query string ready to be used in URL.

```
# active_support cherry-pick
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/to_query'

params = { :bla => 'blablabla' }

Curl::Easy.perform("http://foo.com/bar.xml?" + params.to_query) {|curl|
    curl.set_some_headers_if_necessary
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To pass get parameters with the ruby curb gem you could use

```
Curl::postalize(params)
```

This functions actually falls back to URI.encode_www_form(params) in the curb gem implementation. https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/f89bb4baca3fb3482dfc26bde8f0ade9f1a4b2c2/lib/curl.rb

An example on how to use this would be

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new
curl.url = "#{base_url}?#{Curl::postalize(params)}"
curl.perform
```

To access the curl return string you could use.

```
data = curl.body_str
```

The second alternatives would be

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new
curl.url = Curl::urlalize(base_url, params)
curl.perform
data = curl.body_str
```

Do note that Curl::urlalize might be slightly flawed see this [pull](https://github.com/taf2/curb/pull/126) for postalize that has fix this flaw but the urlalize still uses the old implementation.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply passing a URI escape'd url to the perform(http_get) method?

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html

```
Curl::Easy.perform(URI.escape("http://foo.com/bar.xml?bla=blablabla").to_s) {|curl|
    curl.set_some_headers_if_necessary
}
```

Comment: Well, then the question mark and equals sign get escaped too. Anyway, these are named parameters, and the standard (and most readable) way to pass them is as hash parameters. So I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a different gem? [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) works fairly well and lets you do:

```
RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:params => {:id => 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}}
```

(I realize you asked about Curb. I don't have any experience with Curb, sorry. rest-client has been pretty reliable every time I've used it).