# Ruby Curb (Curl) issue with setting parameters and cookies

Tags: ruby, curb

I've got a series of rather large arrays of entries that I want to post into a remote Jira instance's custom fields, so I'm trying to do it with Curb under Ruby (as their API doesn't allow it, and under SQL it's a bit of a dangerous munge)
I'm open to other suggestions, but I can't for the life of me work out how I can set my cookies with my initial get request, then provide the parameters and appropriate headers for the post

```
c = Curl::Easy.new("http://jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa")
c.verbose = true
c.http_auth_types = :basic
c.username = 'user'
c.password = 'pass'
c.perform
c.headers="X-Atlassian-Token: no-check"
params=    {:fieldConfigId=>'13499',:selectedParentOptionId=>'',:addSelectValue=>'true',:os_username=>'user',:os_password=>'pass',:addValue=>'Barry the Badger',:add=>'Add'}
url="http://jira/secure/admin/EditCustomFieldOptions!add.jspa"
c.http_post(url,params)
c.perform
```

It looks like it's still using the same URL
I've tried using rest_client, but that seems to be misbehaving with cookies, and I do need to set the header above for the atlassian token (so it doesn't request a username/password)
Has anyone got any ideas - or suggestions on what better mechanisms there might be for doing this - or better yet - what I've done wrong ;)
Cheers
Scott

Comment: Jira recommends using HTTP Basic Auth via SSL. Could you try that?

Comment: Hi Joel - I buggered it up somewhat - realised what I've done wrong in the initial stages of cURL construction - as I need to manually authenticate against the websudo page (which is a pain - but it looks like you've only got to do it once per session)
It looks like I need to rewrite my parameters, as it looks like the selectedParentOptionId needs to be a container for two other variables - not sure.  I need to spend a bit more time playing about.
I think I've almost got it cracked though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it
Moved everything around, and had to explicitly set enable_cookies (which is a bit nuts)

```
c = Curl::Easy.new
#set first url
c.url = dashboard
#c.verbose = true
c.http_auth_types = :basic
c.username = username
c.password = password
c.enable_cookies = true
c.headers="X-Atlassian-Token: no-check"
#perform login to first link
c.perform
#puts c.cookies
#prepare url to access websudo
c.url=websudo
c.verbose = true
#set password for websudo form
params={:webSudoPassword=>password}.to_query
#set post
c.http_post(c.url,params)
#prepare all variables for creating new custom field option
params={:fieldConfigId=>cf_config:selectedParentOptionId=>'',:addSelectValue=>'true',:os_username=>username,:os_password=>password,:addValue=>cf_value,:add=>'Add'}.to_query
c.url=addoption
c.verbose = true
c.http_post(c.url,params)
```

Works a treat now, and followed the advice from [Pass GET parameters with Ruby Curb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072502/pass-get-parameters-with-ruby-curb) and used ActiveSupport to_query